# Angular - How to Open POST url in Angular application (POST and Redirect)

Tags: angular, web, post, angular10

I'm having an angular application. In which client is going to POST some data and redirect to my application. I need to read that POST data and do necessary action. Is there any way where i can read POST data.

I tried to simulate by posting test data to my login page. It is showing "**Cannot POST /auth/login**"

Answer (score 1):

angular works only with get requests in any solution (ssr/other).
for getting data in angular u can send get request and in query params send link to some file that have needed data and load it by request from angular.

or use some server node.js/next.js (typescript) and nginx for receive post request without any magic in other services